# Input integral derivative in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: calculus, wolfram-alpha

How to input $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_0^x \sqrt{t^2-t+1} \,dt)$ in Wolfram Alpha?

If i change $dt$ by $dx$ it works, but the output is $\sqrt{t^2-t+1}$, there is no substitution for "$t$" there, if i am correct the result should be $\sqrt{x^2-x+1}$.

Comment: Try something like `d/dx (integral of ln(t) dt from t=0 to t=x)`, for the integrand $\sqrt{t^2-t+1}$, Alpha said standard computation time exceeded. If you change to $dx$ then the integration is just multiplying an $x$, which is not what you intended to do at first.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the way around this is by changing the $dt$ to $dx$.  Trying alternative routes, like suggested by Shuhao Cao, ended up exceeding standard computing time through Alpha, even extending additional computation time.

If you have Mathematica, it provides greater amounts of computation time, but in the case of your posted problem, the result is clearly $\sqrt{x^2 - x + 1}$ without the use of software.

Comment: Ok, changing $dt$ to $dx$ is not what i want. So clearly i cant use wolfram for this kind of problem, it always end exceeding standard computing time. And is not just this particular case, i usually use wolfram to verify results. I will try with Mathematica.